Global raster boundaries are slightly shifted: why so and how to fix it?
I use these rasters:

HWSD2 raster in .bil format

A group of soil parameters rasters inicially  .nc

Another group from the same site also inicially .nc
Also I use DEM and vector river layers.
HWSD2 was imported to GRASS GIS project with r.import command.
.nc were converted to TIFF because r.import for unknown reason doesn't ingest .nc.
What I noticed. When I made a cross product in GRASS of all these layers, HWSD2 (soil types) ans others, there was a shift as . Visually shifted was HWSD layer, because others are corresponding between themselves and comply with river layer.
After that I looked through extents in QGIS where initial rasters were loaded in WGS84. I've found:
 HWSD
 Extent  -179.9999999999996589,-89.9999999999999574 : 180.0000000000001705,89.9999999999999574
 Width   43200
 Height  21600

 VMC
 -180.0000010155100370,-56.0000010157236119 : 179.9998484276194120,83.9999476099618931
 Width   43200
 Height  16800

 THETA,KS
-180.0000010172761620,-90.0000010172996951 : 180.0000010172761620,90.0000010172996951
 Width   43200
 Height  21600



Such inconsistencies. In GRASS the extent is shown for all rasters as 180N 180S 90E 90W, so I can't see if there is any shift.
My question is why HWSD2 raster is shifted. Should I fix the problem on importing or converting or I can change the extend in GRASS (r.region doesn't help).
You can download HWSD2 here
Any of THETA or KS here
And VMC here
UPD: not all raster is shifted, only Siberian and russian soils are shifted. Seems to be incorrectly treated while collecting the HWSD2 raster from different soil databases.
